# Parsing error: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <CCol>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I faced strange bug in vscode...I'm creating an app with react.js.When I write code in js file , the tages are written correctly but when I save the format of code changes so I face this error in run time...For example I write this code :

```
const renderForeigner = (foreigner) => {
            if (foreigner) {
                return <CFormGroup row >
                     <CCol xs = "12" md = "3" >
                    
                    <CSelect custom name = "IDBirthPlace" id = "IDBirthPlace" >
                         { /* <option value="0">Please select</option> */ }
                          <option value = "0" > country</option> 
                           </CSelect >
                            </CCol >
                             <CCol xs = "12" md = "4" >
                                 <CInput type = "number"  id = "CertificateNo" name = "CertificateNo"  autoComplete = "off" />
                    </CCol> <CCol xs = "12" md = "2" >
                    <DatePicker

                value = { passExpireDate }
                onChange = { setPassExpireDate }
                inputPlaceholder = "expiration date"
                shouldHighlightWeekends

                locale = "fa"
                 />
                    </CCol>
                     </CFormGroup >

            }
```

when I save my code changes to this :

`````
const renderForeigner = (foreigner) => {
            if (foreigner) {
                return <CFormGroup row >
                    <
                    CCol xs = "12"
                md = "3" >


                    <
                    CSelect custom name = "IDBirthPlace"
                id = "IDBirthPlace" > { /* <option value="0">Please select</option> */ } <
                    option value = "0" > country< /option>  <
                    /CSelect > <
                    /CCol > <
                    CCol xs = "12"
                md = "4" >
                    <
                    CInput type = "number"
                id = "CertificateNo"
                name = "CertificateNo"
                autoComplete = "off" / >
                    <
                    /CCol> <CCol xs = "12" md = "2" > <
                    DatePicker

                value = { passExpireDate }
                onChange = { setPassExpireDate }
                inputPlaceholder = "expiration date"
                shouldHighlightWeekends

                locale = "fa" /
                    >
                    <
                    /CCol> <
                    /CFormGroup >

            }
````

I don't know what snippet makes these changes or what snippet should I install to solve this problem?
`````

Comment: Make sure your filename has the `.jsx` extension

Comment: There seems to be a missing curly brace `}` at the end to close off the function definition and the `if` statement properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code provides Format on save feature. If you disable that feature your code will not change.

The solution is to press Ctrl Shift + P and search "Open Setting UI". In the open setting UI Search "Format On Save" now you have to just uncheck the checkbox and your problem will solve.